# query to find shops that has all pictures deleted in soft deletable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query roughly:

```
SELECT s.username
FROM  `instagram_shop` s
INNER JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` 
p ON s.id = p.shop_id
WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL 
AND p.deletedAt IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT( p.id ) = NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_PICTURES_IN_SHOP_S
```

I am trying to find shop that all of it's pictures has it's deletedAt set to something. Meaning shops that has all of it's pictures deleted, how can I do so?

I've tried formulating it above, however I am confused on how to find the total number of pictures for shop s.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT s.username
FROM  `instagram_shop` s
INNER JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p ON s.id = p.shop_id
WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL 
AND p.deletedAt IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT( p.id ) = COUNT(SELECT pp.id FROM `instagram_shop_picture pp` WHERE pp.shop_id = s.id)
```

I believe you can't do a count after having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe you can't do a `COUNT` after `HAVING`.

But you *can* do the `COUNT` before, including the results in the query, and run an outer query to filter out the count. You can use `HAVING` or use a `WHERE` in the outer query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.username FROM (
    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.username,
        COUNT(*) AS Total,
        SUM(IF(p.deletedAt IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS SoftDeleted
    FROM  `instagram_shop` s 
    JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p
    ON (s.id = p.shop_id)
    WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL
    GROUP BY s.id, s.username
) AS b;
```

Here you can [find a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e46c/1) that demonstrates the approach (inner query).

## SELECT shops with all pictures soft-deleted, and undelete them

To do this we need the *shops* in this state, and then the *pictures* in them:

```
UPDATE `instagram_shop_picture` u
JOIN ( above query retrieving emptied shops' with their ids ) AS d
  ON ( u.shop_id = d.id )
SET deletedAt = NULL;
```

or *almost* equivalently

```
UPDATE `instagram_shop_picture` SET deletedAt = NULL
WHERE shop_id IN ( similar query retrieving only shops' ids );
```

*almost* because the second syntax requires a query that returns only id's, while the first version can do without removing extra fields.

```
UPDATE `instagram_shop_picture` u
JOIN ( 

    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.username,
        SUM(1) AS Total,
        SUM(IF(p.deletedAt IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS SoftDeleted
    FROM  `instagram_shop` s 
    JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p
       ON (s.id = p.shop_id)
    WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL
    GROUP BY s.id, s.username

) AS d
  ON ( u.shop_id = d.id )
SET deletedAt = NULL;
```

For the second version we need an outer query removing fields we don't need, once they did what they were put there to do:

```
SELECT b.id, b.username FROM (

    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.username,
        SUM(1) AS Total,
        SUM(IF(p.deletedAt IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS SoftDeleted
    FROM  `instagram_shop` s 
    JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p
       ON (s.id = p.shop_id)
    WHERE s.deletedAt IS NULL
    GROUP BY s.id, s.username

) AS b;
```

The outer query in this case isn't very expensive, it acts as a sort of filter for the inner query. In some cases I have found that it can prompt the optimizer to change its choice of indexes, and *that* can have undesired consequences. One can recourse to [index hinting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) to remedy that.

As with all "massive update" queries, **test this in pre-production** and **backup your data first**.

Comment: what if I want to set the deletedAt of pictures from these shops ?

Comment: also I wanted to view the s.username, I don't want to see the Total and SoftDeleted is it possible to hide those two column

Comment: You cannot hide the columns. But you can run an outside SELECT: Select id From ( the sqlfiddle query ) As t; . This will only get you id. To have username, add it to both the inner and outer selects and to the group clause also (i.e.: GROUP BY s.id, s.username) . Superfluous in mysql, yes, but good practice.

Comment: To set deletedAt, you need a different query if you want to do it efficiently. As it is now, I think you would need two more joins and a full scan. Expensive. I need to check this...

Comment: @Iserni yea I am looking for a way to undelete all of this